# SQLCODE=-911 : "warehouser_error_message": "File <<filename>>.csv.zip could not be loaded due to an exception in dashDB

Tags: cloudant, dashdb, cloudant-sdp

The Cloudant Schema Discovery Process (SDP) is reporting the following error message while loading my dashDB database:

```
"warehouser_error_message": "File xxxxxx/xxxxxx_nnnn_nnn_n_n.csv.zip
   could not be loaded due to an exception in dashDB. Reason: <DB2 SQL
   Error: SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, SQLERRMC=68, DRIVER=4.18.60>"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDP locks the database during the **initial load**.  The -911 error indicates there is a lock contention issue.  Ensure you aren't performing any other operations on the database table that is being loaded by the SDP.

For find the current load status, see this question: [How can I tell if my SDP process is still running the 'initial' load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806048/how-can-i-tell-if-my-sdp-process-is-still-running-the-initial-load?lq=1)