# How can I tell if my SDP process is still running the 'initial' load?

Tags: cloudant, dashdb, cloudant-sdp

You cannot run any sql statements on a DashDB that result in locks that will conflict with the schema discovery process (SDP) during the initial load.  See here for more information:

[SQLCODE=-911 : "warehouser_error_message": "File <<filename>>.csv.zip could not be loaded due to an exception in dashDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804646/sqlcode-911-warehouser-error-message-file-filename-csv-zip-could-not)

**Question**:  How can I verify if SDP is running the initial load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log in to the Cloudant dashboard and select the `_warehouser` database.  Inside that database, select the document that represents the SDP that you are trying to verify the status of.  Inside that document, look for the tag `sub_status`:

```
  "replication_status": {
    "yourdatabase": {
      ...
      "sub_status": "initial",
      ...
    }
  },
```

This will be set to `initial` for the initial load and `continuous` when the initial load has finished.